# update the list of directories with only the new ones

Tags: python

I am creating a list (a text file) of all the directories recursively using the code below. Since there are a thousands of sub-directories, I don't want to create the list again and again, but would like to update/insert only the newly created ones from the last time I had listed them.

Is there a good way to do this ?

```
import os, sys
rootdir ="/store/user/"
myusers=['u1','u2','u3','u4','u5','u6','u7']

for myuser in myusers:
    rootuserdir=os.path.join(rootdir, myuser)
    for myRoot, mySubFolders, myFiles in os.walk(rootuserdir):
        for mySubFolder in mySubFolders:
            dirpath =  os.path.join(myRoot, mySubFolder)
            print dirpath
```

Comment: Do you want the new/deleted directories so that you can see what was added/removed, or are you asking so that you can increase the speed?  As @Sven Marnach mentions in his answer, you won't save any time, as you're still running os.walk() against the whole directory.

Comment: Yes, I need the updated list because I would upload them to a database, so if there is no other way than redoing it, I will do so.

Comment: As @Jon Clements mentioned, this is really the kind of task that inotify would be good for (at least on Linux systems), and pyinotify provides a good python interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't save anything by trying to incrementally update your list of folders.  There is no efficient way to delete a line from the middle of a file, nor to insert a line.  Simply writing the whole list again is the most efficient approach, and also the easiest one.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to locate a specific entry in a file would be more resource intensive than just repopulating the list each time.

For performance optimization always try to determine where the true bottlenecks lie before focusing on one specific area.  More times than none, your focus will be in the wrong place when not employing this approach.

Determining the bottlenecks or hotspots should always be one of the first focus areas when refactoring your code.   By doing so, you'll ensure that you are focusing on the areas that have the highest ROI with the least amount of LOE.  A rule of thumb is that you should only attempt to refactor code if you can make the entire program or at least a significant part of it at least twice as fast. [more...](http://robzu.com/how-to-be-a-programmer/)

Answer (score 0):

You could run a one-off process to cache the information in some sort of database (possibly a document orientated one for simplicity), then use pyinotify in a daemon process to keep the database in sync.